# EWS get appointments with reminder <= current time

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to query Exchenge to get app appointments that have set reminder to current time.
I've created simple method that returns one appointment that will start in nearest future:

```
    public Appointment getMyAppointments()
    {
        try
        {
            CalendarFolder cfolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
            CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));every appointment in one hour
            calendarView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Categories);
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = cfolder.FindAppointments(calendarView);

            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

            if (findResults.Items.Count > 0) // Prevent the exception
            {
                items.AddRange(findResults.Cast<Item>());
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Categories, ItemSchema.Body));
            return findResults.Items[0];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This returns me top one appointment that will start in nearest future AND that are active in current hour:

If I plan appointment that starts ad 14:00 and ends at 14:30 my method will return that appointment if I start it at 13:01, but it will also return that appointment if I start in at 14:22.

I would like to change that method so it would return all meeting that have set reminder before current time and didn't start:

So if I plan appointment at 15:00 and set reminder to 15 minutes and I call my method at 14:45 I'll get that appointment.

My idea was to get all appointments in lets say 8 hours, then iterate over them and check if they have `IsReminderSet` and check if `Start`-`ReminderMinutesBeforeStart` is smaller that current time.

**EDIT - this is my temporary solution**

```
    public OWAAppointment GetMyAppointments(int minutes)
    {
        try
        {
            CalendarFolder cfolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
            CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(10));
            calendarView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Categories);
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = cfolder.FindAppointments(calendarView);

            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

            if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                items.AddRange(findResults.Cast<Item>());
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Categories, ItemSchema.Body, ItemSchema.ReminderDueBy, ItemSchema.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart));


            var appointment = findResults.Items
            .Where(item => item.Start >= DateTime.Now)
            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Start.AddMinutes(-1*minutes) < DateTime.Now);

            return appointment // this will return appointment or null
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But maybe this can be done with EWS easier?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done easier. The GetReminders operation for EWS (not the EWS managed API) was introduced in Exchange 2013. Information can be found here: [GetReminders operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn720424%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). To retrieve all current reminders, set the ReminderType to All and the EndTime to the current time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
           xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
           xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
   <m:GetReminders>
      <m:EndTime>2014-05-06T21:00:00Z</m:EndTime>
      <m:ReminderType>All</m:ReminderType>
    </m:GetReminders>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks You for answer, but unfortunately I can't test in on Exchange 2013. I'll get back to this as soon as I'll have test environment.